# How do I properly validate a ModelForm (best practices)?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm that I need to validate. I am currently overriding clean() method with custom validator functions. These validators raise a ValidationError in case something is wrong. If everything is fine - they do nothing. I have two questions:

1. Is this approach a good practice?
2. I am naming my validator functions the following way:
   ensure_SOMETHING (e.g. ensure_circular_reference_nonexistence(...),
   ensure_max_depth_limit_is_respected(...), etc.). Again, is this a
   good practice? I haven't seen others user "ensure" in their function
   names.

To be 100% clear, this is how my clean() method looks like:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ensure_circular_reference_nonexistence(...)
    ensure_max_depth_limit_is_respected(...)
    return super(MyForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're good.
However you should know, cleaning and validation is not the same thing. That's why django forms has the is_valid method and also the clean method.

If what you have done there is validation, as is what it looks, it would be better you extend the is_valid method with your functions.

It doesn't stop you from calling the clean method. In fact, you should call the clean method too.